# How random is my shuffle function?

Tags: r, random

I am programming a psychology experiment, I need to shuffle the order of stimuli for each participant. I have a function which randomly orders my stimuli, which my program then reads out of a .txt file. Does the pseudo-random algorithm which is used by default in sample (as shown in my "shuffle" function below) shuffle things up adequately to realistically be expected not to produce any systematic bias in any stimulus position or pattern of stimulus positions over the course of the experiment (4500 trials)?

```
stimulus <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
shuffle <- function (x) { as.data.frame(sample((t(x)))) } 
shuffle (stimulus)
```

Comment: I can't resist suggesting the results are heavily biased towards the beginning of the alphabet :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say yes, and you can graph this. If it were truly random we would expect a uniform distribution of values at each position in the shuffled order, so let's repeat the experiment a lot and graph the results....

```
#  Repeat experiment 10,000 times
res <- replicate( 10000 , shuffle(stimulus) )
out <- do.call( rbind , res )

#  Plot
par( mfrow = c( 3 , 2 ) )
for( i in 1:ncol(out)){
  hist( out[,i] , main = paste0("Values at position: " , i ) )
}
```

Each histogram is the distribution of values in each position. 5 positions so 5 histograms. There is an even distribution of the possible values at each location so I'd say your values are being assigned to each position with an even probability (which is the default for `sample`).
[image]

Comment: I believe that sampling (using `sample`)without replacement, and not specifying probabilities will result in the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm. This is because after each value is sampled, it renormalized the probabilities (uniform in this case) and samples from the remaining available ones. This means that each permutation as equal probability.

Answer (score 4):

The random number generators in R are excellent - the language is aimed at statisticians. A couple of points.

1. See `?RNG` for details about the random number generators used.
2. Use `set.seed` to make your shuffling reproducible

   ```
   set.seed(1)
   ```
3. You could simplify your code to:

   ```
   stimulus = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
   data.frame(sh=sample(stimulus))
   ```